# How to perform a search operation on Combobox in windows phone 8.1?

Tags: search, combobox, windows-phone-8.1

In  my windows application i am having one combobox. In combobox i am showing many number of items (strings) to user. Now i want to perform search operation on combobox for filter the data. Please any one hep me how to do this. Please anyone help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am trying from last 3 days. Till now I didn't get any solution.please anyone reply me.

Answer (score 1):

Usw Linq to search through list of strings:

```
myComboBox.Items = myData.Where(s => s.Contains(myKeywordTextBox.Text)).ToList();
```

Execute in your search buttons click handler.